# Pillow 2.0.0 tutorial

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to learn pillow 2.0.0 for python, but honestly I have no idea where to start, since I can't find any tutorials or docs, and the one [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is badly structured, it only describes the modules one by one, so I can't get into it.

Do you have any links to:

1. a tutorial/docs
2. a simple piece of code writing a png and saving it to the file
3. a link to a well commented program using imaging library which I can read

Does it makes any difference I'm using python 3.3 on a windows 7 ?

Comment: Pillow is a fork of PIL so you might search for that instead.

Comment: But pillow is an extension, right? Then ther has to be some extra features, and its those I'm interested in hearing about

Comment: Learn the basics first, then worry about the extras. In fact I'm not sure what the differences are.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pillow is a fork of PIL and use from PIL functions and classes. 
You can search PIL tutorial!

[installation Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0) (you can install pip or easy_install in windows then write `pip install pillow` or `easy_install pillow`)

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm

http://www.geeks3d.com/20100930/tutorial-first-steps-with-pil-python-imaging-library/

[http://nadiana.com/pil-tutorial-basic-advanced-drawing](http://web.archive.org/web/20130115175340/http://nadiana.com/pil-tutorial-basic-advanced-drawing)

[http://nadiana.com/pil-tutorial-how-create-button-generator](http://web.archive.org/web/20130115175715/http://nadiana.com/pil-tutorial-how-create-button-generator)

http://pythonvision.org/basic-tutorial

http://python.developpez.com/cours/pilhandbook/php/introduction.php

http://www.riisen.dk/dop/pil.html